# How to take a subgraph of an edge-weighted graph and preserve weights?

Tags: bugs, graphs-and-networks

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 12.0**

---

I need create a weighted graph with given data.

Number of nodes: $53$ $\quad$ Number of edges: $91$

```
gp = 
  Graph[
    Table[data1[[i]] <-> data1[[i + 1]], {i, 1, 91 3, 3}], 
    EdgeWeight -> Table[data1[[i + 2]], {i, 1, 91 3, 3}],
    VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

Then I take out some nodes and get a subgraph.

```
sub1 = 
  Subgraph[gp, 
    {28, 27, 26, 24, 23, 22, 17, 16, 15, 18, 21, 20, 25, 44, 46, 48, 49, 50, 51}, 
    EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight", VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Why do all the weights become $1$?

Comment: Subgraph only returns edges and vertices. This is spelled out in the... wait for it... the documentation. You must add any weights that you want not one.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @ciao I don't see this mentioned in the documentation ... and even if it were mentioned, I would consider it an annoying omission.  Why couldn't `Subgraph` preserve edge and vertex properties?  I see no good reason for that.

Comment: @ilian I really don't see why this isn't considered a bug ... it is not spelt out in the documentation that properties would get lost, nor can I see any reason why this should be the case. Other graph-handling libraries *will* preserve properties when taking subgraphs.

Comment: @ciao I agree with Szabolcs that this is NOT clearly stated in the documentation (I'd expect this in the Possible Issues section)  and though this behaviour might not be considered a bug I do find it rather annoying.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree. This has in fact been reported internally as a bug a while ago. Apologies for my misvote -- I relied on the first comment and neglected to look into it myself. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: @ilian Does this internal report has a CASE number? I would like to add [our standard header](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1610/187) so that it can easily be found with the [SE bug tool](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2736911/bugreport.html)

Comment: @halirutan It has a bug number, but not a case number (because it was submitted by QA and not through support). Nevertheless, this shouldn't stop anyone from sending it to support, as multiple external reports may increase the likelihood of a(n earlier) fix.

Comment: @ilian Thanks. Can someone confirm that this behaviour was introduced when the function `Subgraph` was introduced in version 8?

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now contains `IGWeightedSubgraph`, which can do this very fast. Part of this function are implemented in C to achieve excellent performance. I recommend you use it.

---

I use this workaround:

```
subgraph[wg_?GraphQ, {}] := Graph[{}, {}]
subgraph[wg_?GraphQ, vs_List] :=
 Module[{ind},
  ind = VertexIndex[wg, #] & /@ vs;
  IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[
   VertexList[wg][[ind]],
   WeightedAdjacencyMatrix[wg][[ind, ind]],
   DirectedEdges -> DirectedGraphQ[wg]
   ]
  ]
```

`IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph` is from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/) and differs from WeightedAdjacencyGraph in that it can treat zero elements of the matrix as missing edges (instead of `Infinity` elements).

I will reproduce the source here, as it is written in pure Mathematica:

```
(* When am is a SparseArray, we need to canonicalize it and ensure that it has no explicit value that is the same as the implicit one. *)
arrayRules[am_SparseArray, u_] := ArrayRules[SparseArray[am], u]
arrayRules[am_, u_] := ArrayRules[am, u]

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph::usage =
    "IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[matrix] creates a graph from a weighted adjacency matrix, taking the 0 weight to mean unconnected.\n" <>
    "IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[vertices, matrix] uses vertices as the vertex names.\n" <>
    "IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[matrix, z] creates a graph from a weighted adjacency matrix, taking the weight z to mean unconnected.\n" <>
    "IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[vertices, matrix, z] uses vertices as the vertex names.";

IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam_?SquareMatrixQ, unconnected : Except[_?OptionQ] : 0, opt : OptionsPattern[WeightedAdjacencyGraph]] :=
      WeightedAdjacencyGraph[
        SparseArray[Most@arrayRules[wam, unconnected], Dimensions[wam], Infinity],
        opt
      ]
IGWeightedAdjacencyGraph[vertices_List, wam_?SquareMatrixQ, unconnected : Except[_?OptionQ] : 0, opt : OptionsPattern[WeightedAdjacencyGraph]] :=
    WeightedAdjacencyGraph[
      vertices,
      SparseArray[Most@arrayRules[wam, unconnected], Dimensions[wam], Infinity],
      opt
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

*Update:* In Mathematica 12.0, `Subgraph` preserved edge weights.

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) has a function to do this since version 0.3.97.  Unlike the method using adjacency matrices, this function will also handle weighted multigraphs.

Thus, use `IGWeightedSubgraph` instead of `Subgraph`. Note that the second argument can only be a list of vertices. Unlike in `Subgraph`, edges and patterns are not currently supported.

This function is fast (partly implemented in C), but it preserves edge weights only.  All other properties are discarded.

If you need to preserve all properties, use `IGTake`.  `IGTake[graph, subgraph]` takes the vertices and edges of `graph` that are also present in `subgraph` and preserves all graph properties.

#### Examples

```
<< IGraphM`

IGraph/M 0.3.97.1 (February 4, 2018)

Evaluate IGDocumentation[] to get started.

g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "EastAfricaEmbassyAttacks"}]
```

[image]

```
vs = {"Osama", "Salim", "Abdullah", "Hage", "Abouhlaima", "Owhali"};

sg1 = Subgraph[g, vs]
```

[image]

The graph returned by `Subgraph` is not weighted:

```
IGEdgeWeightedQ[sg1]
(* False *)
```

`IGWeightedSubgraph` returns a weighted result, but all the original styling is lost.

```
sg2 = IGWeightedSubgraph[g, vs]
```

[image]

```
IGEdgeWeightedQ[sg2]
(* True *)
```

`IGTakeSubgraph` preserves all properties (and styling), but it is much slower than `IGWeightedSubgraph`.

```
sg3 = IGTake[g, Subgraph[g, vs]]
```

[image]

```
IGEdgeWeightedQ[sg3]
(* True *)
```

Verify that the edge weights in the subgraphs are correct.

```
Function[graph,
  PropertyValue[{graph, #}, EdgeWeight] & /@ EdgeList[sg1]
] /@ {g, sg2, sg3}
(* {{0.52, 0.48, 0.48, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.48, 0.16}, 
    {0.52, 0.48, 0.48, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.48, 0.16}, 
    {0.52, 0.48, 0.48, 0.36, 0.36, 0.36, 0.48, 0.16}} *)

Equal @@ %
(* True *)
```