# Spatial Display of "Union of Geodesics" in a Random Geometric Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

After reading....

[Finding all shortest paths between two vertices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4128/finding-all-shortest-paths-between-two-vertices)

which addresses an important topic in Mathematica graph visualisation, I use

```
paths[gr_, {i_, j_}] := Module[{sub, dist, indices, dd, nbrs},
  dist = GraphDistance[gr, i, j];
  indices = {};
  dd = dist;
  Reap[Nest[
     Function[{vv},
      dd -= 1;
      nbrs = VertexList[NeighborhoodGraph[gr, #]] & /@ vv;
      nbrs = Pick[#, GraphDistance[gr, #, j] & /@ #, dd] & /@ nbrs;
      Sow /@ Flatten[Thread /@ Thread[vv \[UndirectedEdge] nbrs]];
      Union[Flatten[nbrs]]
      ], {i}, dist]][[2, 1]]]
```

after Heike's answer, then

```
gr = Import["/home/graph.gml"];
ends = {1, 30};
sub = paths[gr, ends];
HighlightGraph[gr, {Graph[sub], Style[ends, Green]}]
```

where `graph.gml` is a spatial network. This appears:

[image]

If, however, I want to display *just* the union of geodesics, I enter

```
Graph[sub]
```

but the graph is no longer geometric (the vertex coordinates have gone):

[image]

How can I keep everything spatial and get `Graph[sub...}`  to give me a geometric graph, instead of this non-spatial one?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89290/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's only for visualization, you can set GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide" :

```
HighlightGraph[gr, Graph[sub], GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"]
```

Comment: This is good. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an inefficient method to ensure you retain the locations of the vertexes in a subgraph.  Start with a graph:

```
g = RandomGraph[{20, 40}]
```

Extract the locations of its vertex coordinates:

```
myvertexlist = VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g]
```

Get the list of vertexes in the path of interest, for instance:

```
q = FindPath[g, 1, 12][[1]]
```

Create the edges:

```
mynewedges = Table[Rule[q[[i]], q[[i + 1]]], {i, Length[q] - 1}]
```

Plot the graph:

```
Graph[q, mynewedges, VertexCoordinates -> myvertexlist]
```

You'll have to apply these techniques to your particular module and graph and highlight styles, but the principle should work.

Comment: Nice, +1 for simple answer.